# How do I flatten an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

On Ruby. I have array of array `c = [["a"], ["b"]]`

How convert it to `c = a + b`

```
c = ["a", "b"]
```

for any array. Maybe it is possible not using other variables.
All array inside not flatten.

```
d = [ [["a"], ["b"]], [["c"], ["d"]], [["e"], ["f"]] ]
```

I need `[ [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"]] ]`

Comment: Are you talking about `Array#flatten` right now?

Comment: flatten is not good for array of array . more deeper   [[["a"], ["b"]]] i need flatter but only one step

Comment: I just edited the post to make the question clearer, I think you edited it too, you might need to do so again.

Comment: yes, notice in the docs it says "recursively".

Comment: On the first example, the input array is 2 levels deep and the output is a flat array (1 level deep). On the second example both the input and the output arrays are 3 levels deep. What's the rule?

Comment: _How convert it to c = a + b_ – are you looking for `c.inject(:+)`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Array#flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) also accepts a parameter.

> The optional level argument determines the level of recursion to
>   flatten.

```
c = [[["a"]], [["b"]]]

c.flatten
# => ["a", "b"]

c.flatten(1)
# => [["a"], ["b"]]
```

Comment: How can this be used to produce the outcome describe in the question (for both examples provided)?

Comment: @axiac flatten will produce outcome from the OP's 1st eg. The second example is a typo (input & output is same). What OP is looking for is 1 level flatten, which  he has mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

Use [flatten](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten)

> Returns a new array that is a one-dimensional flattening of this array (recursively). That is, for every element that is an array, extract its elements into the new array. If the optional level argument determines the level of recursion to flatten.

```
irb(main):001:0> a =  [["a"], ["b"]]
=> [["a"], ["b"]]
irb(main):002:0> a.flatten
=> ["a", "b"]
```

You can control level of recursion `flatten(n)`:

```
irb(main):001:0> c = [[["a"]], [["b"]]]
=> [[["a"]], [["b"]]]
irb(main):002:0> c.flatten 1
=> [["a"], ["b"]]
irb(main):003:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby:

```
c = [["a"], ["b"]]
```

Convert Array of array to Array

```
c.flatten
```

To get the sum of array of array

```
c.flatten.sum
```

Comment: no. d = [ [["a"], ["b"]], [["c"], ["d"]], [["e"], ["f"]] ] => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] I need  [ [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"]] ]

Comment: this delete deeper structure, this is not answer

Comment: This will do it  **[d.flatten.collect { |x| [x] }]**